# Gradient at a point is perpendicular to the level curve, but not always?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I've been trying to geometrically understand why the gradient always points to the direction of steepest ascend, but I found it hard to understand, especially because I found a real life counter example (which is obviously wrong, but I need to find out why). Here it is.
[image]

If I had a topographical map, where the red lines are level curves, the gradient on the blue point should be perpendicular to that place on the level curve. However, the steepest climb is not in the perpendicular diraction, but rather a bit to the left or a bit to the right. This can, I believe, also be applied to infinitesimal differences in functions. So I ask: where is my intuition wrong?

Comment: The problem is that what you did was only draw two arbitrary curves such that near the blue point, in the direction perpendicular to the outmost one, you drew the innermost curve such that it would be very far away from the blue point. **However**, the curves in the set of level curves of some function are **not** arbitrary. And, in fact, in the conditions of the Implicit Function Theorem, the level curves will always be such that the gradient is perpendicular to them. The perpendicularity of the gradient is not general property of sets of curves, it is a special property of **level** curves

Comment: @LourencoEntrudo Oh, thanks, that makes sense

Comment: "rather a bit to the left or a bit to the right": how do yo know ? And if the case is perfectly symmetrical, there is no other way than the middle.

Comment: @ampersander It is important to realize that "*direction of steepest ascent*" is a *local* property which applies to an infinitesimally small neighborhood of the point. If you hike up a mountain and stand where the blue point is in your topo map, the normal to the level curve tells you to move a tiny step in that direction, then draw the new level curve, find the new normal, and repeat until you reach the summit.

Comment: You may see this ( Mu Prime Math on YT)  , very concise and enlightning https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v98uipDYuqU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that can convince you, the plot below shows four level curves of the function $$f(x,y)=(x^2+1)y.$$

And crossing them, there are four curves orthogonal to them, with equation

$$y=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}2+\log x+C}.$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f\colon M\to \mathbb{R}^{k}$ is $C^2$ and the level set $S$ is given by all points $x$ in a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ such that $f(x)=c$. If $c$ is a regular value of $f$ (i.e. its differential at at any point $x$ of the preimage of $c$ has full rank) then $S$ is a submanifold of $M$ of dimension $dim(M)-k$.

Consider a point $x$ on $S$ and a tangent vector $v$ in $T_xS$ and some curve $\gamma\colon (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to S$ in direction $v$, starting at $x$. Then $$
\mathrm{d}f_{x}(v)=\tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}|_{t=0} f(\gamma(t))=\tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}|_{t=0} c=0.
$$
By definition of the gradient
$$
g_{x}(\mathrm{grad}f_{x}, v)=\mathrm{d}f_{x}(v)=0.
$$
Since $v$ was arbitrary you have that the gradient at $x$ is perpendicular to the tangent space at $x$. Since this holds for all points on $S$ you have shown that the gradient is a vector field along the level set $S$ that is everywhere perpendicular to $S$.

Comment: This is much too complicated for this question. This idea is covered in sophomore level mathematics and is easily explained to students who will never learn about Reimannian manifolds or any other kind of manifold.

Comment: It wasn't exactly clear what OPs background is. 
For sophomore level knowledge they may take $k=1$ and $(M,g)$ as the standard Euclidean $(\mathbb{R}^{n}, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^{n}})$. The gradient vector of $f$ is then just the transpose of the Jacobi matrix of $f$. Replace the part with the tangent vectors and the curve by "Take the derivative of the equation $f(x)=c$ along the level set surface".
I disagree that this answer is "too complicated" or "too general". OP might not know which area of math this belongs to and now has some pointers by looking up unknown vocabulary.